# A triangulation of the torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, polyhedra, simplicial-complex

Why is the following triangulation not a simplicial complex for the torus?

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is the 1-simplex [a, d]. Simplicial complexes need their simplices to be uniquely identifiable by their vertices. In this diagram it seems like the "top" [a,d] and the "bottom" [a, d] must be different, yet have the same vertex sets.

Comment: Maybe related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953586  and comments therein.

Comment: @AbhinavVNatarajan Thanks a lot. I understood. In the definition of a simplicial complex, the intersection of any two simplexes is a face of each of them but here the intersection of the top $[a,d]$ and the bottom $[a,d]$ is $a\cup b$ which is not a face of each of them. Is it true?

Comment: @C.F.G Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @M.Ramana I'm not sure I understand your question. The triangulation above is a valid simplicial complex, but is not a triangulation of the torus. The latter would require that the top and bottom halves of each vertical edge be distinct, which isn't the case here.